# Handle a hardkey (i.e. via dispatchKeyEvent) while an options menu is visible (i.e. via onCreateOptionsMenu) in Android?

Tags: android, button, overriding, volume, options-menu

Currently, my activity intercepts volume button key presses dis-allowing the setting of the ringer/media volume while my app is running.  However, if the user presses the menu button, it brings up my options menu but, when this happens, the volume keys are no longer intercepted (i.e. because, seemingly, the options menu appears within it's own activity)... Is there some way for me to override the options menu activity such that, when the user brings up the options menu, I can continue to intercept the volume button key presses?

Comment: does anyone have an answer to this??? Maybe I need to ask the question again different or with different tags??